# vim fw, Fw, tw, Tw, and ; in command mode

Tags: vim, vi

I've been using [shortcutfoo](https://www.shortcutfoo.com) to tighten up my vim muscle memory and I ran across some commands I can't understand even with their animations and explanations.

These are the explanations for the commands:

- fw | Move to next 'w' on line
- Fw | Move to previous 'w' on line
- tw | Move before next 'w' on line
- Tw | Move before previous 'w' on line
- ;  | Repeat last f, F, t, or T

I've tried using these commands in my vim but they don't seem to do anything noticeable.

Comment: In normal mode, `f<char>` moves the cursor to the next character `<char>` on the same line.  Rinse and repeat for the others.

Comment: If they're not doing anything noticeable, then you probably don't have any `w` characters on your current line... Maybe you need to try `ft` or `fs` or something else to search for things that actually exist on your current line...

Comment: Basically, f, F, T and t will move to a character in the same line, which you specify along with them. For example, if you press f. it will find dot and move cursor to that place. If you type Fw, it will search towards start of the line for character w. If the character doesn't exist, you won't notice anything.

Comment: I totally misinterpreted the command as w being the movement instead of the literal character. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to link:

https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/vim/cheatsheet

Search keyword: `Intermediate Text Navigation I`.

Hover in icon camera preview. You can see an example to imagine easy.

Example:

- **fw | Move to next 'w' on line**:

[image]

- **Fw | Move to previous 'w' on line**

[image]

- tw | Move before next 'w' on line

[image]

- **Tw | Move before previous 'w' on line**

[image]

- **; | Repeat last f, F, t, or T**

[image]

Similar with other key shortcut.

Comment: So Tw considers "before" to be "before you get there"?